# What does this phrase mean 给你操床头柜里去

Tags: translation, slang

Seems to be some kind of internet phrase?

Comment: Did some Google search, the result is, it came from a 表情包 (Expression package) [我的女友嘴很贱表情包](My girlfriend has a foul mouth expression package) http://www.cntylm.com/armmzf/

If you want the translation... this post will be R-rated

Answer (score 1):

It depends .
Sometimes it means some passionate thing between lovers.
When you are fight with someone , the meaning of this phrase is abuse，just like fuck off in English.（actually it is more serious than fuck off ，but i don't know much about dirty words in English  ）
At last ，this is a rare case ， joking with friends .

Answer (score 0):

''bang you very hard so your head hits the headboard(of the bed)''. Here 床头柜 refered to the head of the bed. Somehow there isn't a very common word meaning ''headboard'' in Mandarin，so we use 床头柜(closet at the head of the bed) instead. This setence may be used in dirty talk.

Answer (score -3):

It means having very rough sex, essentially. (let you fuck from bed to the closet.) Generally used by female only, and so if a girl tell you that, you are a lucky guy and if a guy tell you that, he want you to get him from behind, which is obviously gay if you are into that.

- 给你 let you
- 操 fuck
- 床头 bed
- 柜里 inside the closet
- 去 go

Comment: I think it should at least be split up • 床头柜 / • 里